# IAR compiler is not recognizing some variables

Tags: compiler-errors, avr, iar

Using Atmel provided code for the ATA5702 auto keyfob which has an internal 8 bit AVR.

Within the main routine, the compiler treats variables differently. I have three variables

A1 a locally defined byte int8_t A1 = 0;

DDRB register with address defined using a SFR_B macro in a SFR.h file

TW1BR register with address defined using a SFR_B_EXT_IO_R macro in a SFR.h file

When I compile and debug I get a warning saying A1 is defined and set but never used. When I read values at a break point, A1 shows only that it's a byte but never shows the value. TWB1R always reads zero no matter what I set it to and DDRB works fine reading the value set.

Why is it treating these variables differently and not recognizing a local variable?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: A1 doesn't exist in your compiled code, the compiler is aware that the variable does absolutely nothing and it doesn't bother putting it into your assembly code.  TWB1R and DDRB are volatile thus always have to exist, but I can't explain why the debugger can see the value of one but not the other.